# Apply lambda with shift function to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a formula of "PPG" (previous period growth") and get stacked when it comes to multiple columns (for one column, it works well).

Here is the example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,3,2,2,3,1,3],
               "Date": [20200109, 20200204, 20200307, 20200107, 20200108, 20200214, 20200314],
               "A": [20,10,40,40,10,20,30], 
               "B": [20,30,40,50,20, 30, 10]})
```

when I need to calculate difference between values in one column it's ok:

```
df['new']=df.sort_values(['ID','Date']).groupby('ID')['A'].apply(lambda x:x/x.shift(1)-1)
```

but I do not know how to solve it for two different columns (A and B). The code I'm trying to use is:

```
df['new']=df.sort_values(['ID','Date']).groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.A/x.B.shift(1)-1)
```

and it returns error: *incompatible index of inserted column with frame index*

If anyone can please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code , `apply` create the multiple index, so we need make the index same as df , so we can assign the value

```
df['new']=df.sort_values(['ID','Date']).groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.A/x.B.shift(1)-1).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @YOBEN_S for help and explanation.  It works!